# Manually setting GitHub languages?

Tags: github

GitHub appears to auto-detect the project language type.  However, it has failed on a couple of mine.

Is there a way to set that manually, or is there some keyword/phrase I should set to trigger it?

I'd presumed it goes by file extension as it properly detects my Modula-2, Propeller Spin, and Java repos.  However, it only identifies about half my Assembly repos properly (and they all have .asm files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears that it only detects the type properly if the filename extensions are in lower case characters.  Several of my old projects go way back from when caps was the standard for full filenames.  Creating an empty token file in the GitHub web UI with a lowercase extension of the appropriate type will trick it into displaying the proper language type in the repository screen.

Comment: This was true before March 2015. It changed with [pull request #2087](https://github.com/github/linguist/pull/2087) to the Linguist project (used to detect languages on github.com).

Comment: That's odd as it still wasn't working even in late 2016.  I haven't been working on those projects yet in 2017, so can't say about now though...

Comment: Could be that it didn't update. Language statistics are only updated if you push to the repository.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `.gitattributes` file to add or override filename and extension patterns (or vi/emacs lines).

```
*.ASM linguist-language=Assembly
```

Github's code library responsible for file type statistics and syntax highlighting selection is called [Linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist#overrides). You can open a pull request for a change to [languages.yml](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml#L287) if you believe that you are not the only one affected by this case sensitivity problem.

`Assembly:
  type: programming
  color: "#6E4C13"
  aliases:
  - nasm
  extensions:
  - ".asm"
  - ".a51"
  - ".inc"
  - ".nasm"
  tm_scope: source.assembly
  ace_mode: assembly_x86
  language_id: 24`